# Unit Test old Javascript functions with Jest

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs

I have following small test where I am expecting `getOrderDetails` to be called within `openOrderPage`

`js/__tests__/background.js`

```
test('should call getOrderDetails', () => {

    const getOrderDetails = jest.fn();
    openOrderPage(request, {}, {});
    expect(getOrderDetails).toBeCalled();

  });
```

`js/background.js` has following function

```
function openOrderPage(orderURL) {

  window.open(orderURL, '_blank');
}
```

but I am getting following error:

```
ReferenceError: openOrderPage is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous>.test ()
    at Object.asyncFn ()
    at resolve ()
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at mapper ()
    at promise.then ()
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:160:7)
```

Problem is, how can I test my other functions within `background.js` so that Jest can find them.